# Angular 2 router ignores the empty route

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

My app.routing module includes the following routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'path1',
  loadChildren: 'app/modules/path1/path1.module#Path1Module',
  canLoad: [AuthenticatedGuard]
}, 
{
  path: 'path2',
  loadChildren: 'app/modules/path2/path2.module#Path2Module',
  canLoad: [AuthenticatedGuard]
}, 
.
.
.
{
 path: 'login',
 loadChildren: 'app/modules/login/login.module#LoginModule',
 canLoad: [NotAuthenticatedGuard]
},
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/defaultPath', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthenticatedGuard] }];
```

When the app loads it takes me directly to path1 module, not the defaultPath. The path1 routing module has this configuration

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: Path1Component,
  canActivate: [AuthenticatedGuard],
  children: [
  { path: '', component: Path1ChildComponent }
]}];
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the Path1 module being imported into the app.module and this was somehow causing the issue. When I removed it from app.module routing worked as expected.